# What cashflow value should I consider to calculate NPV?

Tags: stock-analysis

I'm trying to figure out how to use correctly NPV formula

which is given by the formula

```
NPV= Rt/(1+i)^t
```

where:
Rt=Net cash inflow-outflows during a single period t
i=Discount rate or return that could be earned in alternative investments
t=Number of timer periods
​

I'm wondering how can I possibly use that formula being in front of a stock's  financial sheet (e.g. on yahoo finance looking Apple stock sheet)

I know that:

- i (discount rate) can be approximately estimated over 10-y Treasury yield + some % points.
- t (period) can be assumed as number of years
- Rt ? What Should I use as Cash flow? Cash flow **per share**? over TTM? or LFY? or

From my understandings the NPV value should be then compared to the actual stock price to understand its intrinsic value. That's why I'm thinking on using Cashflow per share.

Any recommendation on how to use and apply correctly the formula over a stock financial report
is very welcome.

Comment: Application of the present value formula to valuing a business is called building a discounted cash flow (DCF) model. The math behind and the mechanics are not complex but building them properly so that they can succesfully guide investment decisions is usually tricky and requires training and experience. Ideally, one should have studied corporate finance, financial accounting, and economics before starting to build DCF models in addition to having a number of years of real life business experience. I would not recommend trying to use DCF models unless you have such training and experience.

Comment: Well I was actually thinking Im almost there. Just missing to know what is the CF to be used in the formula. From your comment it looks like there’s much mote gap than what it seems from formula to its usage… :/

Answer (score 1):

When valuing a stock, you never use just one cash flow. You use *multiple* cash flows over time, summing them all up.

In a typical Discounted Cash Flow (DCF) model, you forecast out the total net cash flows of a company for several periods, and typically the cash flows are different over time as the company grows, stops borrowing money, etc. At some point you assume that the remaining cash flows are constant so you can apply a single formula to treat the company as a perpetuity and eventually get back to one number.

Those forecasts require a lot of assumptions that have a large margin of error. But it can be a decent test on whether a stock is "cheap" or "expensive".

Whether you convert everything to per-share values or compute a final total NPV and then divide by the number of shares is up to you.